# How to resolve OutOfMemoryError in a Dataproc cluster running a pyspark code?

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc, airflow-2.x

I am working on a pyspark code, where I connect to a BigQuery table and import that source table as a df. The process requires to have the df column names renamed. To do so I define a dictionary, basically hardcoding it.

```py
cols_new_to_original = {'colA_new':'colA_original', 'colB_new':'colB_Original'...}
```

This has around 3000+ key:value pairs, further I am using the following step to rename the columns of the df using `cols_new_to_original`.

Code:

```py
# Replace column names using the cols_new_to_original
  df = df.repartition(30)
  for new_name, original_name in cols_new_to_original.items():
      df = df.withColumnRenamed(new_name, original_name)
```

While doing so I am getting following error:

```java
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/5642d3d6-77f7-4615-aae9-dcd4e1c9bbdb/scorer.py", line 132, in <module>
    score()
  File "/tmp/5642d3d6-77f7-4615-aae9-dcd4e1c9bbdb/scorer.py", line 90, in score
    df = df.withColumnRenamed(new_name, original_name)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 2475, in withColumnRenamed
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1304, in __call__
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 111, in deco
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o118.withColumnRenamed.
: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(Array.java:75)
```

Below is my cluster configuration:

```py
cluster_config = {
        "master_config": {
            "num_instances": 1,
            "machine_type_uri": "n2-standard-2",
            "disk_config": {
                "boot_disk_size_gb": 500
            }
        },
        "worker_config": {
            "num_instances": 8,
            "machine_type_uri": "n2-standard-8",
            "disk_config": {
                "boot_disk_size_gb": 1000
            }
        },
        "secondary_worker_config": {
            "num_instances": 1,
            "machine_type_uri": "n2-standard-8",
            "disk_config": {
                "boot_disk_size_gb": 1000
            },
            "preemptibility": "NON_PREEMPTIBLE"
        },
        "software_config": {
            "image_version": "2.0.27-centos8",
            "optional_components": [
                "JUPYTER"
            ],
        "properties": {
            "spark:spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled": "true",
            "spark:spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors": "1",
            "spark:spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors": "10",
            "spark:spark.shuffle.service.enabled": "true"
            }
        }, .............................
```

Initially I also tried `"spark:spark.executor.cores": "2"` and `"spark:spark.executor.memory": "16g"`, but I get the same issue.

Comment: The OOM seems to be with driver instead of executor, so try tuning `spark.driver.memory`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Dagang for the suggestion. The OOM was with driver instead of executor, and tuning `spark.driver.memory` helped.

I also had to make some changes to how I was renaming the columns.

New Code:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
[col(c).alias(cols_new_to_original.get(c, c)) for c in df.columns]
```

This worked.

Comment: Glad it worked! Wondering why the new way of renaming is needed?